# Android LVL : how to modify/recompile ServerManagedPolicy.java in the licensing module?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-lvl, android-app-licensing

I would like to add some lines of code (namely some Log.d to check some values) in the `ServerManagedPolicy.java` file of the Google LVL library.

This library appears as a folder 'library_licensing' in the 'Project' tree of my project in the left panel of Android Studio.

I can modify the `ServerManagedPolicy.java` file in Android Studio, see it in the Finder ('Reveal in Finder'). I see that this file is in my bundle on the disk.

My problem is that when I modify this file, my modifications do not seem to be taken into account. How to recompile this file or the whole library_licensing module?

Thanks!